# expl3: keys enabled under certain condition

Tags: expl3, l3keys

In my package, there are options like:

```
\keys_define:nn { crefthe-setting }
  {
    , variant       .tl_set:N           = \l__crefthe_variant_tl

    , nom           .meta:n             = { variant = Nominativ }
    , gen           .meta:n             = { variant = Genitiv   }
    , dat           .meta:n             = { variant = Dativ     }
    , akk           .meta:n             = { variant = Akkusativ }

    ...
  }
```

The short cuts, such as `nom`, however, should only be enabled when `\languagename` is equal to `ngerman`. How should one achieve such conditional keys?

Below is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l__crefthe_variant_tl
\keys_define:nn { crefthe-setting }
  {
    , variant       .tl_set:N           = \l__crefthe_variant_tl

    , nom           .meta:n             = { variant = Nominativ }
    , gen           .meta:n             = { variant = Genitiv   }
    , dat           .meta:n             = { variant = Dativ     }
    , akk           .meta:n             = { variant = Akkusativ }

    , unknown       .code:n             = {}
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \TestFunction { m }
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l__crefthe_variant_tl {}
    \keys_set:nn { crefthe-setting } { #1 }
    \tl_use:N \l__crefthe_variant_tl
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{english}

\TestFunction{nom} (\languagename) % should be empty

\selectlanguage{ngerman}

\TestFunction{nom} (\languagename)

\end{document}
```

Comment: `babel` has hooks so you could set the keys when you switch to `ngerman` and unset them when you switch to `english`. Is that what you mean? It isn't entirely clear to me what you're trying to do or what 'enabling' means exactly. I guess you actually want the token list to be valid but empty if English is current?

Comment: @cfr I think the effect should rather be on non-German (and English is just the example at hand). So activating them when `ngerman` is selected would be feasible using the `babel` hooks, but I'm not sure whether `babel` provides an end-of-language hook.

Comment: @Skillmon Wouldn't you then get an error rather than nothing in other languages?

Comment: @cfr the idea would be to activate them on German and deactivate them when German-scope ends. But I'd have to read `babel`'s documentation to see whether that's possible, and I know from trustworthy sources that no one reads documentation.

Comment: @Skillmon So would `\TestFunction{nom} (\languagename)` not give an error in that case?

Comment: @cfr depends on how you implement "deactivating". If an error is what you're after then you could implement it that way. If you want silent ignoring you can achieve that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following evaluates `\languagename` (there is a warning in the manual that due to catcode weirdness recommends using the `iflang` package, but I guess catcodes shouldn't be an issue if we use string based comparison) when you try to set those keys and will throw a warning (you could change this to an error) when the keys are used in the wrong language.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\msg_new:nnn { crefthe } { unavailable-key }
  { Key~ `#1'~ unavailable~ outside~ of~ language~ `#2'. }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__crefthe_lang_key:nn #1#2
  {
    \str_if_eq:VnTF \languagename {#1}
      { \keys_set:nn { crefthe-setting } {#2} }
      {
        \msg_warning:nnxx { crefthe } { unavailable-key }
          { \l_keys_key_tl } {#1}
      }
  }
\tl_new:N \l__crefthe_variant_tl
\keys_define:nn { crefthe-setting }
  {
    , variant .tl_set:N = \l__crefthe_variant_tl

    , nom     .code:n   = \__crefthe_lang_key:nn {ngerman} { variant = Nominativ }
    , gen     .code:n   = \__crefthe_lang_key:nn {ngerman} { variant = Genitiv   }
    , dat     .code:n   = \__crefthe_lang_key:nn {ngerman} { variant = Dativ     }
    , akk     .code:n   = \__crefthe_lang_key:nn {ngerman} { variant = Akkusativ }

    , unknown .code:n   = {}
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \TestFunction { m }
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l__crefthe_variant_tl {}
    \keys_set:nn { crefthe-setting } { #1 }
    \tl_use:N \l__crefthe_variant_tl
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{english}

\TestFunction{nom} (\languagename) % should be empty

\selectlanguage{ngerman}

\TestFunction{nom} (\languagename)

\end{document}
```

There is likely a smarter way to do this, but this should do.